# Single pass algorithm for finding the topX percent of items

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for a single-pass algorithm for finding the topX percent of floats in a stream where I do not know the total number ahead of time ... but its on the order of 5-30 million floats. It needs to be single-pass since the data is generated on the fly and recreate the exact stream a second time.

The algorithm I have so far is to keep a sorted list of the topX items that I've seen so far. As the stream continues I enlarge the list as needed. Then I use `bisect_left` to find the insertion point if needed.

Below is the algorithm I have so far:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from random import uniform
from itertools import islice


def data_gen(num):
    for _ in xrange(num):
        yield uniform(0,1)

def get_top_X_percent(iterable, percent = 0.01, min_guess = 1000):

    top_nums = sorted(list(islice(iterable, int(percent*min_guess)))) #get an initial guess

    for ind, val in enumerate(iterable, len(top_nums)):
        if int(percent*ind) > len(top_nums):
            top_nums.insert(0,None)
        newind = bisect_left(top_nums, val)
        if newind > 0:
            top_nums.insert(newind, val)
            top_nums.pop(0)

    return top_nums

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num = 1000000
    all_data = sorted(data_gen(num))
    result = get_top_X_percent(all_data)
    assert result[0] == all_data[-int(num*0.01)], 'Too far off, lowest num:%f' % result[0] 
    print result[0]
```

In the real case the data does not come from any standard distribution (otherwise I could use some statistics knowledge).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this program work? What is the question? For a review of your code try [codereview.se]

Comment: yes, it works just fine (albeit slowly) ... I was wondering if anyone had any trickier way of doing this ... I didn't know about Code Review ... is there any way to migrate it?

Comment: for working code its a good bet to try [codereview.se] this site is mor for code that isn't working

Comment: What if at some point during iteration you're storing the top 100 items, and then an item comes along that is smaller than the 100th item, but not by much. Then, later on you expand to store 101 items, but the previous item you discarded is now bigger than all the items you now see... In other words, you discarded the real 101st item. Did that make sense?

Comment: @Lasse: That makes sense ... can't see any way around that either.hmmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any way to actually do that reliably, as the range denoted by the "top X percent" can grow unpredictably as you see more elements. Consider the following input:

```
 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
```

If you wanted the top 25% of elements, you'd end up picking 101 and 102 out of the first ten elements, but after seeing enough zeroes after there you'd eventually have to end up selecting all of the first ten. This same pattern can be expanded to any sufficiently large stream -- it's always possible to end up getting misled by appearances and discarding elements that you actually should have kept. As such, unless you know the exact length of the stream ahead of time, I don't think this is possible (short of keeping every element in memory until you hit the end of the stream).

Comment: He'll have to create a worst case data structure. If he knows it can't be more than 30 million items, he'll have to grab the top X items where X is calculated relative to 30 million. Then, discard the unwanted values once he knows the actual count.

Comment: That's a good idea ... I can make a worst-case guess on the upper-bound and then shrink it afterwords.

Answer (score 4):

You **must** store the entire stream in memory.

**Proof:** You have a sequence of numbers, n<sub>1</sub>,…,n<sub>k</sub>.  The value of *k* is unknown.  How do you know when n<sub>i</sub> can be forgotten?  When you have seen x*k/100 numbers greater than n<sub>i</sub>.  However, since *k* is unknown, you can never do this.

So the only "one-pass" algorithm must store the entire sequence in memory.

Comment: As @Lasse commented: you **must** store the entire stream **unless** you know an upper bound for *k*.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have discussed, you can't really do a whole lot better than just storing the entire stream in memory. Consider doing it that way, especially since 5-30 million floats is probably only 40-240 MB of memory which is manageable.

Given that you store the entire stream, the algorithmically fastest way to get the topX percent is by first finding the cutoff element (the smallest element that is in the topX percent) using a linear-time selection algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Then, make another pass through the stream and filter out all the elements smaller than the cutoff element.

This method is linear time and linear space, which is the best you can hope for.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the output from running this with cProfile. It seems that your code is doing fine, as most calls are 0.000 (percall). It seems its slow simply because you have many items to process. If you wanted to optimize, you'd have to try and `pop` less items, as that is what has it has been called 999999, which seems to be unnecessary.

```
Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:48(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:74(_Feature)
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __future__.py:75(__init__)
    1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 bisect.py:1(<module>)
    1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 hashlib.py:55(<module>)
    6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hashlib.py:91(__get_openssl_constructor)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 os.py:743(urandom)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:100(seed)
1000000    0.731    0.000    0.876    0.000 random.py:355(uniform)
    1    0.003    0.003    0.004    0.004 random.py:40(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:647(WichmannHill)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:72(Random)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:797(SystemRandom)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 random.py:91(__init__)
    1    2.498    2.498   13.313   13.313 test.py:12(get_top_X_percent)
    1    0.006    0.006   16.330   16.330 test.py:3(<module>)
1000001    0.545    0.000    1.422    0.000 test.py:8(data_gen)
1000000    1.744    0.000    1.744    0.000 {_bisect.bisect_left}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_md5}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha1}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha224}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha256}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha384}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_sha512}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {binascii.hexlify}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {function seed at 0x100684a28}
    6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
    6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
1000004    0.125    0.000    0.125    0.000 {len}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.exp}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.log}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {math.sqrt}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
1009989    0.469    0.000    0.469    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
 999999    8.477    0.000    8.477    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
1000000    0.146    0.000    0.146    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.close}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.open}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.read}
    2    1.585    0.792    3.006    1.503 {sorted}
```

BTW, you can use cProfile with:

```
python -m cProfile test.py
```

Comment: all of the `pop` calls come from the fact that in this I have the WORST CASE scenario, when the data is already sorted.